# Angular test $httpBackend Unexpected request and regex undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a simple controller with init function:

```
 init() {
    this.PositionService.getPagePosition(this.$state.params.name).then(( res ) => {
      this.position = res.data.position;
    })
  }
```

And my positions service:

```
  getPagePosition( name ) {
    return this.$http.get(this.appConfig.api.positions + '/' + name);
  }
```

My test:

```
describe('position list page', function() {

  var scope,
      $httpBackend,
      controller;

  beforeEach(module('module'));
  beforeEach(inject(function( $controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_, _PositionService_ ) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    controller = $controller('PositionsController', {
      $scope          : scope,
      PositionService : _PositionService_,
    });
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  describe('PositionsController', function() {

    it('should get the position', function() {

      $httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/localhost:3000\/positions\/[a-z]+/).respond(200, {
        data: {
          id: 2
        }
      });

      controller.init();
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(controller.position.id).to.equal(1);

    });

  });

});
```

My problem is that i get this error:

```
 Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:3000/api/positions/undefined
    No more request expected
```

Why the paramater is undefiend and why i get this error?

Comment: You are no stubbing `this.$state.params.name` - method `getPagePosition()` returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jasmine and ES5 the test will look like:

```js
angular.module('module', [])
  .controller('PositionsController', function(PositionService, $state) {
    this.init = function() {
      PositionService.getPagePosition($state.params.name)
        .then(function(res) {
          this.position = res.data.position;
        }.bind(this))
    }
  }).service('PositionService', function($http, appConfig) {
    this.getPagePosition = function(name) {
      return $http.get(appConfig.api.positions + '/' + name);
    }
  });


describe('Position list page', function() {

  var scope,
    $httpBackend,
    controller;

  beforeEach(module('module'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.module('module').value('appConfig', {
      api: {
        positions: 'http://localhost:3000/positions'
      }
    })
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_, _PositionService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    controller = $controller('PositionsController', {
      $scope: scope,
      PositionService: _PositionService_,
      $state: {
        params: {
          name: 'someParamValue'
        }
      }
    });
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  describe('PositionsController:', function() {

    it('Gets the position - init()', function() {
      
      var stubId = 2

      $httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/localhost:3000\/positions\/[a-z]+/).respond(200, {
          position: {
            id: stubId
          }
      });

      controller.init();
      
      expect(controller.position).not.toBeDefined();
      
      $httpBackend.flush();
      
      expect(controller.position).toBeDefined();
      expect(controller.position.id).toEqual(stubId);
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```