# write unit test for login method using karma with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I try to write a test for my authentication controller using karma with jasmine.
My function is :

```js
myApp.controller('LogController',
        ['$http',
            '$scope',
            '$sessionStorage',
            '$window',
            function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $window) {
            $scope.log = function () {
            $scope.authenticate = true;
            $http.post('/log', {user: $scope.user, _method: 'POST'}).then(function (data) {

     if (data.access.state == 202) {
               if (data.data.response.all.data.type === "ADMIN" ||data.data.response.all.data.type === "OWNER") {
                     $window.sessionStorage['session'] = parsedData;
                     $scope.authenticate = false;
                     window.location.href = "/";
                            }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry you don't have permission ");
                            }
                        }
     else if (data.access.state == 401) {
              alert(data.access.error[0]);
                        }
     else {    
   alert("ERROR!!!!!");
   window.location.href="/auth";
          }
                    });
                };
```

I try to test firstly if the function log was defined.This test pass well and then I try to test if the function log call this url 'auth/log' using POST method and this second test failed

this is my test case :

```js
  describe('LogController', function() {
  var $scope, controller;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $location = jasmine.createSpyObj('$location', ['url']);
    controller = $controller('LogController', {
      $scope: $scope,
      $location: $location
    });
  }));

  it('should set Login function', function() {
    expect($scope.log).toBeDefined();
  });
      
  
  it('should call auth/log on $scope.log()', inject(function($httpBackend) {
       $scope.log();
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/log').respond();
    $httpBackend.flush();
  }));
```

I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

I can't find my mistake can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('LogController',
  function($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $window) {
    $scope.log = function() {
      $http.post('/log', {
        user: $scope.user
      }).then(function(response) {

        if (response.data.access.state === 202) {
          $window.alert("Sorry you don't have permission");
        }

      });
    };
  });



describe('LogController', function() {
  var $scope, controller, $location, $window;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.module('myApp').value('$sessionStorage', {})
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$window_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $window = _$window_;
    $location = jasmine.createSpyObj('$location', ['url']);
    controller = $controller('LogController', {
      $scope: $scope,
      $location: $location,
      $window: $window
    });
  }));


  it('calls alert if user has not privilages', inject(function($httpBackend) {
    
    spyOn($window, 'alert');
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/log').respond(200, {
      access: {
        state: 202
      }
    });
    
    $scope.log();
    
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Sorry you don\'t have permission')
  }));

})
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Your respond in `$httpBackend.expectPOST('auth/log').respond()` is empty, so `data.access.state` throws error.

Take a look into [Angular JS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST('auth/log').respond(status, responseObject); // feel free to put correct status and {access: {state: 'some state'}} into respond method
```

Comment: @Akino response object should look like `{access: {state: 'some state'}}`. Please study my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937089/angular-test-httpbackend-unexpected-request-and-regex-undefined/31938444#31938444

Comment: Yes you're right . Thank you very very much @Krzysztof Safjanowski

Comment: But I have a question @Krzysztof Safjanowski. I put 202 as a value of my state.however the result of my test is  `"ERROR!!!!!"` is it logic ?

Comment: @Akino Are you passing HTTP headers as part of response? It should be part of response headers instead of response body. What value are you passing for first argument of `respond()` method?

Comment: yes I do. I put 200 as first argument like this : `$httpBackend.expectPOST('auth/log').respond(200,{access: {state: 202}});`

Comment: In the controller you have `$http.post('/log')` but in the test `$httpBackend.expectPOST('auth/log')` - witch path is correct? You can also add section `afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });` to verfiy that all queries are supported in test

Comment: The correct one is $http.post('/log') I just change it in my post. When I try to add `afterEach(function() { $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation(); $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest(); })`; All my test failed because $httpBackend is not defined. where should I declare it .I try to put it as an argument of function like I did before but it doesn't work..Its my first experience with angular tests I m really lost :(

Comment: @Akino Please read my similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937089/angular-test-httpbackend-unexpected-request-and-regex-undefined/31938444#31938444 where I show how to add `$httpBackend` in `beforeEach` section

Comment: It's ok now @Krzysztof Safjanowski I can add the  `beforeEach` section to my test code and it work fine. But I still have the same result which is :   `"ERROR!!!!!"` and I don't have any other error message !!

Comment: So can you please tell me @Krzysztof Safjanowski how can I be sure that all queries are supported in test ?because I still don't understand why I have `"ERROR!!!!!"` as result even if I put 202 as state

Comment: @Akino in `if (//test permission then :` you miss `)` and the expression for test permission

Comment: No @Krzysztof Safjanowski it's ok in my code I didn't put it in the post because it will be too long and it was not the part which cause my first problem.I have just edited my post and put the expression for test permission

Comment: In your answer @Krzysztof Safjanowski  the alert is shown if the sate = 202 but in my test I should verify if state=202 and then if the user havn't permissions the alert must be shown else he will be redirected to an other url.I don't know how can I add the second test which allow me know if the user has the right permissions or no

Comment: I put a `console.log(data.access.state)` before the permission test and I found that it was undefined.@Krzysztof Safjanowski cane you tell me please if this is normal

Comment: try `console.log(data.data.access.state)` - so I have change data to response to avoid duplication